# How to validate date must be come after today’s date with datefield in blackberry

Tags: blackberry

So I make a `DateField`:

```
DateField date=new DateField("Date : ",System.currentTimeMillis(),DateField.DATE_TIME);
```

how to validate the input of the date must be come after today date? i dont know how to get values from datefield.

Thanks in advance

Comment: "i dont know how to get values from datefield." Class `DateField` has a getter method `getDate()`. It returns a `long`. `System.currentTimeMillis()` also returns a `long`.  Am I misunderstanding something here?

Comment: ya thats the problem, i use getDate but its a long type, what im thinking if i can get the values from datefield then i can compare with today date(using calendar.getInstance())

Comment: Why do you want to do that?  `System.currentTimeMillis()` gives you the current date/time in milliseconds.  Compare the value set on the DateField with the current time obtained from the system.

Comment: Umm compare with current time is from calendar.getInstance()? sorry i am still new to blackberry

Comment: I have never done anything for BlackBerry, but that API is based on Java.  The `Calendar` class used by BlackBerry is directly from Java, so you can do something like `Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis()`. Then compare the two `long` values.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this:

```
if( date.getDate() < Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis())
{
  // Do whatever
}
```

Comment: Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis();
getTimeInMillis() cant be used

Comment: You need to add more code and provide a more detailed explanation of what is the problem that you need to solve.  There is not enough information to provide a meaningful solution to your problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can use date.getDate() to return input date/time in milliseconds (epoch)

```
long inputDate = date.getDate() ; 

// Then you can get current date/time in milliseconds with :

Date now = new Date() ;
long currentDate = now.getTime() ;

if (inputDate > currentDate)
{
   // valid input in future
}
```